# How do I create a ruby script that runs script/console and then runs commands using that environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I've noticed I've been having to do:

```
bundle exec script/console
<wait for console to load>
require migration
generate some data
```

a lot... and I was wondering if there is a way to have this all in a bash script or something. so i could just do ./generatedata and have it run the above commands.

Comment: Why do you wanna a `ruby` script? This could be done easily with `bash` script as a just a sequence of commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that custom rake tasks are an awesome tool for when you have work which requires running code in the rails environment. Check out this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks

Comment: +1, and quite easy to implement as well--for non-interactive, repeated tasks (hint hint) this is the preferred solution, I'd think. Plus it can be run very quickly via rails-sh.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a one-off command in the console, you can use the `rails runner` command. So if you had a ./generatedata.rb script which performs the ruby commands you want to execute in the console, you can just call `rails runner ./generatedata.rb` and it will run your ruby script in the rails environment against the database. Alternatively, you could add the shebang line to the ./generatedata.rb script: `#!/usr/bin/env rails runner`. Then you only need to execute the ./generatedata.rb script and it will use `rails runner` automatically.

Comment: Also +1, although I might make it a task. One reason is that as a task it can be run trivially via rake-sh, which means it can be much faster than a command-line rails runner script.

Comment: You're right. This is an alternative for when you really do just have a quick task that doesn't really feel like it needs to be a rake task. It doesn't happen very often though, so I agree that usually a rake task would be the way to go.